# He contradicts himself "on the regular"

Tags: slang, phrase-origin

This phrase was used to describe Donald Trump in an article in *Salon* magazine.

> Donald Trump is a better politician than a lot of people give him credit for. Granted, he often has no idea what he’s talking about, he contradicts himself ***on the regular***, he has a repellent personality, he’s a misogynist and a bigot, and it feels like he stumbled ass-backwards into the Republican presidential nomination.

- [*Salon*](http://www.salon.com/2016/05/09/ditch_dangerous_donald_the_democrats_trump_strategy_underestimates_his_abilities/)

According to multiple slang dictionaries, including *[Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/on-the-regular)*, "**on the regular**" is well-established slang for "often," "frequently," or "routinely."  It is mainstream enough to be found in reputable print journalism (see below for that).

> regularly; frequently. Also *on the reg*.
>
> Ex: *I hit up that spot on the regular.*

- *Online Slang Dictionary*

Searching Ngram isn't very useful for this question because the phrase can be part of typically grammatical sentences, like "*It wasn't on the regular menu*."

Most of the anecdotal uses that I've been able to find have been within the last year or two, but I expect that it must have been a slang expression for longer than that in order to show up in the likes of *Esquire* and *Rolling Stone*.

**Questions**:

- When did this phrase come into vogue?
- Is it uniquely American slang, and did it originate with a specific region or culture?

---

To vouch for the legitimacy of this phrase and prove that this is a serious question, here are few uses from major print publications:

> Although it's damn near impossible to wake up flawless like Beyoncé **on the regular**, it is possible to get pro concealing tips from her makeup artist

- [*Cosmopolitan*](http://www.cosmopolitan.com/style-beauty/beauty/how-to/a56511/how-to-color-correct/) (2017)

> It doesn't matter whether you and your buddy from work go out for drinks **on the regular** and play on the same intramural co-ed after-work bowling team: You still shouldn't trust them to keep your secrets.

- [*Esquire*](http://www.esquire.com/lifestyle/how-to/a52699/how-to-go-on-the-run-from-the-law/) (2017)

> Understanding West Virginia has taken on a newfound relevance since the aftermath of the most recent Presidential election. The state has occupied an unlikely place at the center of American politics so far this century, inspiring thinkpieces **on the regular** every four years.

- [*Rolling Stone*](http://www.rollingstone.com/culture/scott-mcclanahan-appalachian-literary-outsider-w489229) (2017)

Comment: Don't think I've ever come across it in BrE, if that helps.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Can't say that I have either. It almost makes me cringe because it brings to mind the "-ly drop", e.g. "It was done regular" vs. "It was done regularly".

Comment: @marcellothearcane See my comments below guys. It's an Americanized slang particularly from the African American community and the hip hop/rap subculture. Obviously it just means, "I do it regularly". I agree it's a horrible manifestation. A lot of times these things happen, I personally believe, across the entire world, not just America, especially in rap type genres/cultures b/c they are looking for rhyming type words and phrases. Not only that but it has become a part of that culture to invent new phrases as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kace36 No pressure one way or another, but if you have sources or want to write a comprehensive answer, I'd definitely be interested.

Comment: I'm almost on board with@Kace36 s "forced rhyme" theory, and definitely would wager it being urban slang,  I can't quite rule out it being a casual reference to "on the regular shift" , or "on the regular schedule" or "on the regular bus"  etc.  "What have you been doing ?"  ,  "I don't know, just on the regular" without feeling they need to specify which part of their normal schedule was "regular".  Just thoughts.

Comment: @Kace36 "Horrible"?? What's so bad about it. I rather like it.

Comment: Maybe more luck if you search "on the reg"

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Ok maybe *horrible* was too strong. I can agree it's not so bad to my ear after many years of hearing it. I guess what I'm saying is I really believe most of those phrases are forced from the fact that people need ways to rhyme words. There was an *enormous* explosion of euphemisms in the 90's and early 00's, which still continues today. That was around the time that rapping became very popular. Sure, we could argue that our world is smaller, social sharing, internet advances, etc., and certainly they had an effect, but I find it more than coincidence that this happened.

Comment: @Kace36 It's a cool finding, but I find it rather rude to call a dialectical phrasing "horrible." What makes you think there are more euphemisms being coined nowadays vs 1917?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I didn't mean to sound rude. I'm sorry if it offended you. Regarding the euphemisms it's just very obvious even anecdotally over my lifetime. Look at how many there are today; and the explosion of them in the late 80's and throughout the 90s with hip hop culture. We would expect some of that to a degree from the information age, social media sharing, etc... But there are loads and loads. Are you saying you disagree or would just like me to give examples of why or something beyond anecdotal evidence? I don't mean any offense. Just curious about what you're thinking. Thx!

Comment: @Kace36 I'm not personally offended but thanks for apologizing. I was just curious if you had any data beyond anecdotes; I have no idea how much slang there was before 2000 :)

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Ah I see. Sure. To be honest it was mostly anecdotal on that part but I have done some research on the topic. For one just look at this site: http://theweek.com/articles/470305/17-euphemisms-sex-from-1800s. It contains 17 euphemisms for sex. Now look at this one: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+sex,+sexual+intercourse.html. There are 190 euphemisms for sex here. And that's not even an exhaustive look into this phrase or euphemisms in general.

Comment: We would expect there to be more today. Some of that is obvious with the information age and social media; but the growth's exponential. A vast majority of those on the 190 word list are directly linked to words/euphemisms from the past 30ish years. And that's just "one" concept (that of sex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I've done some additional research and I've found even earlier usages of the phrase, **on the regular**.

The rapper *"Defari"* on his album, *The Next Chapter*, in 1995, on the song *"Big Up"* has this verse:

[Link to Defari lyrics for the Big Up song](https://genius.com/Defari-big-up-lyrics)

> Verse 3: Lyrics are gold plus steel for the raw deal
>
> Feel MC's and DJ's nuff respect y'all real
>
> Low caps I rock **on the regular**
>
> Brim covers my eyes so ducks can't see their predator
>
> Facefirst when I disperse yet another verse

**INTERESTING NOTE:**

You can see how he is using the phrase in line 3 to rhyme with line 4, **"see their predator"**.

**ADDITIONAL FINDINGS**

In 1996 there was a compilation album released by Interscope Records called [Insomnia](https://www.discogs.com/Various-Insomnia-The-Erick-Sermon-Compilation-Album/release/750180). It included a song called, [On The Regular, by Duo](https://genius.com/Duo-on-the-regular-lyrics). That song has various verses with the phrase: **on the regular**

---

**HYPOTHESIS**

I do remember hearing this term around the early to mid 90's in the US. I was around 20 or so at the time. Of course it's *possible* that it was used earlier than this but I think it's highly likely that it started around this time, with songs like these, as a result of trying to rhyme words in rap songs.

It's important to note that it became very common, and is even more so to this day, especially in African American and hip hop/rap culture, to create new phraseology and euphemisms. For one it helps create an identity (which is something the early rap culture - especially in the US - really wanted badly) along with the added value of allowing you to rhyme songs that would otherwise be nonsensical.

My position is that this is how we have come about many of the colloquialisms of today. This *on the regular* phrase is one but there are many, things like: "throw up a deuce" (to show a "peace" symbol), "roll a fatty (or blunt)" (talking about smoking pot), *bling* (jewelry), *rims* or *20's* (nice wheels on a car), "gimme a 40" (pronounced "foe-tee") to mean 40oz beer (it was common in the "hood" or ghetto for people to buy 40oz alcoholic beverages). There are tons of these types of words and phrases and many variations. "I'm out" (leaving) comes from rap's early "Audi 5000 G", which just meant, "I'm outta hear guys". Audi 5000 was a popular and desired car by that culture at the time. It eventually morphed to simply "Audi" and then finally "out" or "outta" or "outtie".

---

**FINAL THOUGHTS**

So, basically, these words are a way to create identity within subcultures and they are also the mechanism to create rhymes for songs.

**I would peg the origin of this particular phrase at around 1990-1995, probably occurring on the west coast and/or southern parts of the United States. Defari was a west coast [California] rapper at the time.**

Comment: I enjoyed your thoughts, although I'd take issue with many of them. The "I'm out" association with Audi, seems particularly far fetched to me. I'd guess "I'm out" was used in poker perhaps even back to the late 1800's , and "Lets get out of here" far predated urban culture of the 1980s, or even the 1950s.  "outta" is a completely normal and expectable contraction like 'would'a" 'could'a" and others. I'm sure sports announcers in the 1920s didn't always enunciate "out of" clearly when saying the ball is "out of bounds" even if they were careful to spell it better.

Comment: @Tom22 Perhaps I should reword that little section. I agree with you about some of those references. What I was getting at is that as a youngster the phrasing "Audi 5000 G" became popular in urban and rap culture America. It eventually morphed to just Audi. I agree they may have been borrowing it from already used versions of "outta here", etc. I just meant to show how the terms so common today, "I'm *out*", or , "*outtie*",  are likely evolved from those early "Audi" references in "hood" America. But I should probably take a moment to clean it up, I agree. I'll do so later. Thx!

Comment: I was curious about this one... here is a great page with rap citations using the term https://www.therightrhymes.com/on-the-regular  They show Ice-T using it in 1991 with lots of early rap citations fitting your memory. It was hard to find the first citation as most lyrics on the web do not include the phrase http://ohhla.com/anonymous/ice_t/og/th_tower.ict.txt

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Rap music but the uses I found don't look like forced rhymes ... although I can hear the rhythm of the word "regular" being fitting for a phrase end to the extent I understand the rhythmic conventions. I looked up a number of them (interesting how the lyrics aren't always consistent at the lyric sites) and none of them seem forced to me.  Going through a number a few years after use the phrase mid sentence. I'm not sure that came from one isolated remix version Ice-T used.  It was interesting looking it up and I do think fitting into rap is a plausible start

Answer (score 1):

The first use I can identify is from Dr. Dre's 1999 track [Xxplosive](https://genius.com/Dr-dre-xxplosive-lyrics)
on the album "2001":

> Pimping bitches on the regular, I put that on the G
>
> A hustler and a player, nowadays it pays to be

I can personally attest to having first heard this in use between 1999 and 2003 in the form of "hooking up on the reg". This was from white American musicians on the West Coast (Portland, Ore.) heavily influenced by hip-hop artists including Dr. Dre and Snoop Dogg.

Answer (score -1):

This thread is from July but I was just now looking up the phrase as it has exploded across my local demographic--middle aged white SF Bay Area folks-- in the last year or so. While some of us may be plugged into hip hop culture it seems like diffusion from younger people. Without knowledge of hip hop origins, it sounded to me pleasingly down home. Associated phrasing like "On the daily"  is also heard, if less common.

Comment: Answers are expected to be substantial and to contain citations to documentation which support their argument. This kind of answer is below the standard of the site. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please note this is not a discussion forum, but instead is a Q&A site. Anything typed in the Answer box must therefore answer the Question. What you've typed here doesn't answer *when it came into vogue* or *what region/culture it originated in*.